Can we rely on reference when it comes to changing Map items changing?
My code
for(FieldDefinition def : [SELECT  
        QualifiedApiName,
        EntityDefinitionId,
        EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName
    FROM FieldDefinition 
    WHERE EntityDefinitionId in :entries
        and Datatype like 'Master-%' ]) {
        String[] tempo = mdEntityFields.get(def
            .EntityDefinition
            .QualifiedApiName);
        if(tempo == null) {
            mdEntityFields.put(def
                .EntityDefinition
                .QualifiedApiName, 
                new String[]{def.QualifiedApiName});
        } else {
            tempo.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
        }

it works cause
 for(String key : mdEntityFields.keySet()) {
        system.debug(mdEntityFields.get(key));
    }

shows both single and array entries. tempo is the matter - looks like it's just ref to a map element and we can easily change the value by this way.
Is it true?


shows both single and array entries.

To be more accurate, it shows array entries with one or more entries. In your map's data type, you can't mix arrays and strings.

tempo is the matter - looks like it's just ref to a map element and we can easily change the value by this way. Is it true?

To be more accurate, the map contains a reference to a list in the heap. Using the new keyword allocates memory on the heap, and returns a reference. That reference is then placed into the map. The way this is worded suggests that if we assign a new list to tempo, it would replace the list in the map as well.

Is it true?

Aside from the technical inaccuracies of the previous description, this is true. The reference from the map's value has been copied to tempo, so any instance methods that alter tempo's content will be reflected in "both" places, since they are actually pointing to the same object on the heap.
